# Iterating over array of JSON objects in TypeScript gives me individual characters at indices

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I have an array of JSON objects received from an API call.

```
data = [{
      "notificationId": null,
      "notificationText": "xXXX YYY",
      "notificationType": "typeA",
      "fromId": 2,
      "toId": 9,
      "timestampCreated": {
        "epochSecond": 1493898875,
        "nano": 0
      }},
      {
        "notificationId": null,
        "notificationText": "YYYYYYY,
        "notificationType": "typeB",
        "fromId": 3,
        "toId": 9,
        "timestampCreated": {
          "epochSecond": 1493898903,
          "nano": 0
        }}
      ]
```

I want the individual Notification objects, by iterating over this array
My Notification interface looks like below

```
interface Notification {
      notificationId: number;

      notificationText : string;
      notificationType : string;
      fromId:number;
      toId:number;
      timestampCreated: Date ;


 }

notif: Notification[] = [];
.
.
this.notif =data;

for(var i=0;i<this.notif.length ;i++){
 console.log("notification text at "+this.notif[i].notificationText);
 //this gives undefined
//and it loops through all the characters of the data
// not just twice
}
```

Can some one help, I am very new to angular2/ typescript world.

Comment: are you using it in angular template ? as in the tagged topics u have mentioned angular

Comment: impossible , send use your whole code

Comment: @Timothy have you parsed your JSON before trying to access?

Comment: @Jayakrishnan : thanks , that was the problem. What I thought was JSON object was actually JS object , Json.parse solved it.

Comment: your object has a problem! You did not close the first }!

Comment: @M98 : That was a typo from my side, when i depersonalized the data. The real issue was I assumed it was an array of JSON object , but it  turns out it was JS objects, I need to JSON.parse() before I could treat it as JSON objects. Although the server returns the List of JSON objects, somehow in angular it was being mapped to JS object.

Comment: Did you solve the problem now?

Comment: @M98 : yes got it working now :), Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering this as I figured out what was the problem. In the above snippet, the array of objects is actually array of JS objects not JSON objects. So I needed to parse the objects before I could use them as JSON. A simple JSON.parse(data) fixed the issue.